# Azure B2C Custom Policy Error "AADB2C90239: The provided token failed signature validation. Please provide another token and try again."

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are working on an application that uses the LTI 1.3 specifications, which sits on top of the OpenId Connect 1.0 specification. The open id connect specs allow for initiating login from a 3rd party. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ThirdPartyInitiatedLogin.

Our use case is we don’t want a login screen to appear. We do not have any SelfAsserted technical profiles. We've done an OpenId Connect flow using the Identity Experience Framework (custom policies) up to the point where the 3rd party issues an id_token and it’s posted to the Azure B2C url https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

We have found out that the Azure B2C is not using the jwks_uri endpoint found in the .well-known/openid-configuration metadata endpoint that we specified in the TechnicalProfile.

The error that we are receiving is:

```
AADB2C90239: The provided token failed signature validation. Please provide another token and try again.
```

When I copy the id_token and use the jwks_uri endpoint from the 3rd party well-known endpoint that we specified in the TechnicalProfile to validate the token, it is a valid token.

What is Azure B2C using to validate the signature of the id_token posted to https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp?

The technical profile looks like this:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LTIAdvantageOpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>Lti Advantage OpenIdConnect Flow</DisplayName>
      <!-- OpenIdConnect as per the Lti 1.3 specs (http://www.imsglobal.org/spec/security/v1p0/#openid_connect_launch_flow) -->
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"></Protocol>
      <Metadata>
        <!-- We are parsing this in the middleware function so we can use this claims resolver because they shadow it with the client_id of azure b2c -->
        <Item Key="client_id">{OAUTH-KV:lti_client_id}</Item>
        <!-- This checks that we are the ones the token is intended for -->
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">{OAUTH-KV:lti_client_id}</Item>
        <!-- Required to specify the type (http://www.imsglobal.org/spec/security/v1p0/#step-2-authentication-request) -->
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <!-- Required by lti specs (http://www.imsglobal.org/spec/security/v1p0/#step-2-authentication-request) -->
        <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
        <!-- We do want to inject some variables -->
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <!-- Just in case we have multiple custom policy files -->
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <!-- Disable some dumb defaults -->
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Lti posts it's own client_id in the form body and Azure B2C has client_id in the header, these two don't work well together -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiClientId" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:lti_client_id}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <!-- Required for the LMS -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiMessageHint" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:lti_message_hint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <!-- Required to OIDC -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiLoginHint" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <!-- Required for OIDC -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" DefaultValue="none" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- We will cross this bridge when we get there -->
        <!-- Here are some just for now -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiMessageHint" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:lti_message_hint}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiClientId" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:lti_client_id}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ltiLoginHint" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Share the OIDC metadata document. Can you also paste a sample token with its header.

Comment: Here's the metadata endpoint: https://api.stukent.com/integration/v1/canvas/.well-known/openid-configuration?subscription-key=5abbb3635e9040b385caf316678ab8c2 and here's a link to an example JWT token https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALq5YyUXc1pq0ZLqxUepKI7hYQXFgX2A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the technical profile, and if possible a correlationId?

Comment: @JasSuri just updated the question with the technical profile

Comment: @ChaseW. - something seems odd here - you didn't directly update your question; rather, you accepted a different user's updates ([Chass Willden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13906751/chase-willden) proposed it, as a fairly substantial rewrite). Is that user, and your user, the same? It doesn't really make much sense otherwise...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, that was me on my work account, I accidentally updated the question with that account.